# MDN JavaScript exercise using additional variable

Tags: javascript, variables

just trying to learn some JS via the MDN website and a bit confused to why they are using one variable to store the result of the loop and then again another variable to store 2nd variable, see example

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Useful_string_methods

Scroll down to the exercise "Filtering greeting messages"

You will see the code below on the MDN page:

```
var list = document.querySelector('.output ul');
list.innerHTML = '';
var greetings = ['Happy Birthday!',
                 'Merry Christmas my love',
                 'A happy Christmas to all the family',
                 'You\'re all I want for Christmas',
                 'Get well soon'];

for(var i = 0; i < greetings.length; i++) {
  var input = greetings[i]; // They assign it here first
  if(greetings[i].indexOf('Christmas') !== -1) {
    var result = input; // Then they assign input to result here
    var listItem = document.createElement('li');
    listItem.textContent = result; // Then they use result, WHY?
    list.appendChild(listItem);
  }
}
```

Now, why can't **listItem.textContent = result** be *listItem.textContent = input*

I've tested this and it works assigning *input* but just would like to know what the reason behind this method of assigning the result of the loop into two different variables.

Thanks

Comment: It shouldn't really make a difference. They are not applying any sort of transformation on the greetings[i] itself so assigning it to a separate variable or not will result the same.Provides better readability if assigned to variable.

Comment: The code is likely adapted from elsewhere, you're correct that the second assignment is redundant, *input* could be used instead of *result* (and instead of the subsequent *greetings[i]* too). I'd rename *input* to *greeting*. ;-)

Comment: Thanks guys, I thought it didn't, and yes even using 'listItem.textContent = greetings[i] does the job.